# Getting an error when deploying firebase with node.js

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am following the functions tutorial on firebase page to deploy my website on firebase hosting, but it keeps giving me error

```
Port 9005 is already in use

Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
```

Logs say this:

```
Building nodejs source
Could not find functions.yaml. Must use http discovery
Serving at port 9005

FetchError: request to http://localhost:9005/__/quitquitquit failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9005
```

I tried to do `lsof -i tcp:9005` to see what is running on the port, but terminal did not answer with anything(

Comment: `I am following the functions tutorial` could you provide the link

Comment: It's the one on firebase page. The link is with the project name, so you won't be able to access it, unless you create your own project(

Comment: Hi @EfimRubin, was my answer helpful ?

Comment: Yep, thanks. Didn't see the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue might be caused if the firebase CLI is not up to date, you can review the current version using `firebase --version`. If your firebase version is kind of old, you can update it using `npm install -g firebase-tools`.

Also, you can use the following command: `firebase serve --only functions --port=9005`, in that way you can change the port you want to use.

Answer (score -1):

In case you are using a VPN, try switching it off.

Solved my problem.